# Error creating bean with name *

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

i am doing that tutorial at the moment:

https://github.com/ubilife/tutorials/tree/master/spring/tutorial4

When I clone the repository everything works exactly like it is writte there.

The tutorial had among others this class:

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("schema.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);        
    }

}
```

Now I tried to make use of what I've learned. I use SpringBoot with Intellij Ultimate 20017 and I wrote among others that class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringRootConfig {

    @Bean(name = "scriptedDataSource")
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("schema.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("scriptedDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("jdbcTemplate()");
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

First I had the Problem of duplicate Beans which Intellij could not handle. I solved that by use Qualifiers as you can see.

But now I got a new Error which I cannot solve with google.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-28 14:38:50.428 ERROR 2020 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptedDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/SpringRootConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'datasource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'datasource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:450) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:196) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.build(EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.java:270) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringRootConfig.datasource(SpringRootConfig.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.SpringRootConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e8fdc42.CGLIB$datasource$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.SpringRootConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e8fdc42$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$39d24068.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringRootConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e8fdc42.datasource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:141) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:279) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:447) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

So first of all I dont understand why cloning the tutors code is working fine and as soon as I try it fails (I even copied for test reasons his config.java but still get errors!)

And of course it would be super nice if you can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you a lot!
If you need any more files please just ask.
My Repo is here https://github.com/realsony/h2TestEnv/tree/master/src

Comment: It doesn't work because the author of the tutorial doesn't understand how a Maven project is supposed to be organized and saved into a VCS (and thus probably doesn't know a whole bunch of other things). Youtube is for lolcats videos. Use the official Spring documentation and guides. The sql script should be under src/main/resources. the target directory is for stuff generated by the build, and should thus not be saved in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception that you posted, it looks like it cannot find your schema.sql file:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Make sure your schema.sql file is in the right place, or update your code to point to where your schema.sql file actually is.